# Adding multiple facets to one variable

Tags: python

I'm playing around with the following class to just practice my Python skills:

```
class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self, settings, actors):
        self.settings = int(settings)
        self.actors = actors
        actors = []
        new_setting = settings = settings + 1

class Actor(object):
    def __init__(self, name, wage):
        self.name = name
        self.wage = wage

    def addActor(self):
        self.name = name
        self.wage = wage
        self.actors.append(name)




Scene1 = Scene(3, ["Tom Hanks", "Meg Ryan"])

Scene1.addActor(Actor("Paul Giamatti"))
```

I want to be able to add multiple features to the variable 'Actor'.
So for example I want to give Tom Hanks an age and a wage etc.

I tried to do this by defining several sub-variables in the function addActor but that gave me errors. Do I have to create a subclass called Actors and do it that way?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "sub-variable"?

Comment: What I mean is that I want one variable to have multiple types data inside it. Is this simply the definition of a class then?

Comment: yes, you have to define a `Actor` class, that you can put in the list `self.actors`.

Comment: Yes. Actor would not be a subclass of Scene, since an actor is not a type of scene. It's just a separate class, and Scene would contain multiple instances of it.

Comment: Ok so this all makes sense. And I've tried it out. However I don't understand how I will be able to use Actor inside Scene now...

Comment: I've updated the code in the initial question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to define another class for `Actor`, see example below

```
class Actor(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, wage):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.wage = wage

class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings
        self.actors = []

    def addActor(self, name, age, wage):
        actor = Actor(name, age, wage)
        self.actors.append(actor)

    def listActor(self):
        for actor in self.actors:
            print "Actor name:", actor.name
            print "Actor age:", actor.age
            print "Actor wage:", actor.wage

# Usage
scene = Scene({"light":True, 'time':'day'}) # settings can be a dictionary depends on your use case 
scene.listActor()
print scene.settings
```

Comment: Thank you, that was great help. This opens up for a much better structure. Very informative.

Comment: Good to know that helped.